# With pouchdb-find should you be able to specify a field with dot notation?

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

I'm attempting to unify my queries against Cloudant and PouchDB.  In doing so I have to use the newer 'find' methodology.  The selector/field syntax works as expected against the Cloudant DB, but when trying to run it against PouchDB, using pouchdb-find, there seems to be something missing as far as the field specification.

I have the following fields specified:

```
"fields": ["_id", "info"]
```

and receive the following as a result against a local PouchDB:

```
{
   "_id":"85-somedude-1456174210512",
   "info":{
      "zeeId":"85",
      "lastUser":"somedude",
      "lastSaved":"2016-02-23T18:12:06.389Z",
      "version":"0.1.0",
      "id":0
   }
}
```

"info" is an object with multiple properties on it and the entire object is returned.  That's what I would expect.

When I try to do this, against the same PouchDB:

```
"fields": ["_id", "info.lastSaved"]
```

I don't get anything except "_id":

```
{
    "_id":"85-somedude-1456174210512"
}
```

I always receive a null/undefined value when trying to access info.lastSaved.  The lastSaved property is always present on the docuemnt, but seems to not be accessible via the 'dot' notation that Cloudant specifies.  When using "info.lastSaved" on a Cloudant find, the "info" object is returned with only a single "lastSaved" property, as is expected.

Is there a way to make this work when using pouchdb-find?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug. Could you please report it on the Github issues page? https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find/issues